# Post html form to restlet

Tags: java, html, restlet

I have an `html form` that I need to submit to a `restlet`. Seems simple enough but the the form always comes back empty.

This is the form:

```
<form action="/myrestlet" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" size=50 value=5/>
    <input type="text" size=50 value=C:\Temp/>
    (and a few other input type texts)
</form>
```

The `restlet`:

```
@Post
public Representation post(Representation representation) {
    Form form = getRequest().getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm();
    System.out.println("form " + form);
    System.out.println("form size " + form.size());
}
```

I also tried getting for form like this:

```
Form form = new Form(representation);
```

But it always comes as `[]` with size 0.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Here's the workaround I'm using:

```
String query = getRequest().getEntity().getText();
```

This has all the values from the `form`. I have to parse them, which is annoying, but it does the job.

Comment: The request parameters are missing.

Comment: @RomanC can you elaborate?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with the code above, I just see some typos in HTML code.

Comment: And what are the typos in the HTML?

Comment: Typos are just values without quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the correct way to get values from a submitted HTML form (with content type 
`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) within a Restlet server resource. It's what you did in fact.

```
public class MyServerResource extends ServerResource {
    @Post
    public Representation handleForm(Representation entity) {
        Form form = new Form(entity);

        // The form contains input with names "user" and "password"
        String user = form.getFirstValue("user");
        String password = form.getFirstValue("password");

        (...)
    }
}
```

In your case, the HTML form isn't actually sent because you didn't define any attribute `name` for your form. I used your HTML code and the sent data is empty. You can check this using the Chrome developer tools (Chrome) or Firebug (Firefox).

```
POST /myrestlet HTTP/1.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8182
Referer: http://localhost:8182/static/test.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

You should use something like that for your HTML form:

```
<form action="/test" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="val1" size="50" value="5"/>
  <input type="text" name="val2" size="50" value="C:\Temp"/>
  (and a few other input type texts)
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

In the case, the request would be:

```
POST /myrestlet HTTP/1.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8182
Referer: http://localhost:8182/static/test.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

val1=5&val2=C%3A%5CTemp
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. Just to clarify, I needed to give a name to the input fields and not to the form itself.

Answer (score 2):

here is a little bit simpler way to achieve this, it directly declares the Form as parameter of the Java method:

```
public class MyServerResource extends ServerResource {
    @Post
    public Representation handleForm(Form form) {

        // The form contains input with names "user" and "password"
        String user = form.getFirstValue("user");
        String password = form.getFirstValue("password");

    (...)
    }
}
```